# Finding solutions of $z^2=x^2+y^2$ where $\gcd(z, y) =1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is there an easy way to find the solutions of $$z^2=x^2+y^2$$ where $\gcd(z,y)=1$?

I apologize if this is a duplicate

Comment: All solutions in positive integers are given by $z=s^2+t^2$ and $x=s^2-t^2$, $y=2st$, or the other way around, where $s\gt t$ and $s,t$ are relatively prime of opposite parity. Wikipedia will have this, among others, in its article on Pythagorean triples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These triples $(x,y,z)$ are called "primitive Pythagorean triples" because they are the integer side lengths of right triangles, and they have no common factors (note that $\gcd(z,y) = 1$ implies $\gcd(z,x)=1$ ... why?).

The triples have a general form that André Nicolas mentioned in a comment. [This Wikipedia article on some structure that these triples have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples) is very well-written for learning about the subject for the first time, unlike most Wikipedia articles on math topics.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help!